# Vb.net Login using OdbcConnection

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

I am using Postgresql for my database, i want to create an App where the user login their account, i have this logic , and i am getting this error **System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'** why i am getting this error?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim Username = Username_TextBox1.Text
            Dim Password = Password_TextBox2.Text
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim ds = New DataSet
            Dim i As Integer
            Try
                Using MyCon As New Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};database=YouthRecord;server=localhost;port=5432;uid=postgres;sslmode=disable;readonly=0;protocol=7.4;User ID=*****;password=*****;"),
                    cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM YouthApp_tableuser WHERE `username` " & "='" & Username & "' and " & "password='" & Password & "'", MyCon)

                    If ds.Tables("YouthApp_tableuser").Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        For i = 0 To ds.Tables("YouthApp_tableuser").Rows.Count - 1
                            Username = ds.Tables("YouthApp_tableuser").Rows(i).Item(1).ToString
                            Password = ds.Tables("YouthApp_tableuser").Rows(i).Item(2).ToString
                        Next
                        If (Username = Username_TextBox1.Text And Password = Password_TextBox2.Text) Then
                            Username = ""
                            Password = ""

                            MainForm.Show()
                            Me.Hide()
                        Else
                            MsgBox("Invalid User! Please Enter Correct User Name and Password.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid!")
                            Username = ""
                            Password = ""
                        End If
                    End If

                    MyCon.Open()
                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

this is the error

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
Try
   Using MyCon As New Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};database=YouthRecord;server=localhost;port=5432;uid=******;sslmode=disable;readonly=0;protocol=7.4;User ID=*****;password=*****;"),
   cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT id, username, password FROM ""YouthApp_tableuser"" where username='" & Username & "' and password='" & Password & "' ", MyCon)
   MyCon.Open()
   dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
       If ds.Tables("YouthApp_tableuser").Rows.Count > 0 Then
             If (Username = Username_TextBox1.Text And Password = Password_TextBox2.Text) Then
                 Username = ""
                 Password = ""

                 MainForm.Show()
                 Me.Hide()
               Else
                 MsgBox("Invalid User! Please Enter Correct User Name and Password.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid!")
                  Username = ""
                  Password = ""
                End If
       End If

   End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

i get the same error

[image]

Comment: The exception is pretty clear: you try to access a property of a databale which does not exist in the dataset. So `ds.Tables("YouthApp_tableuser")` returns Nothing and you call `.Rows` on Nothing -> exception.

Comment: ... and how should `YouthApp_tableuser` be in `ds? You crreate a new dataset and never fill it.

Comment: you mean, may query is wrong? @AlexB

Comment: No, but you execute it too late. If you want to check table `YouthApp_tableuser` you have to load it before your username/password check. (Btw... what is the loop for? You overwrite Username and Password everytime)

Comment: So `MyCon.Open() dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)` should be directly after declaring the OdbcCommand. And you can throw away that DataSet, just work with the DataTable

Comment: @AlexB. can you please post your answer? if you dont mind

Comment: I´m at work. Will do later if no answer is given yet.

Comment: oh, okay okay @AlexB. God bless

Comment: Yikes, plain-text passwords AND sql injection. Do you _want_ your system to be hacked? Because either one of those on their own would already pretty much guarantee it. Both together is what the lawyers might call gross negligence or malpractice.

Comment: And, as of the update, the code loads the results into the `dt` variable, but the if condition checks the `ds` variable. This is the kind of thing I'd expect even a first year student to be able to spot on their own.

Comment: oh, i start learning .net 4-5 days ago, im sorry, im still noob

Comment: I just searched on google sample codes using postgressql database

Comment: @Mary you only need a dataset if you want to load multiple tables. Also you make you familiar with the concept of parametrized quiers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 Try
                Using MyCon As New Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};database=YouthRecord;server=localhost;port=5432;uid=*****;sslmode=disable;readonly=0;protocol=7.4;User ID=*****;password=*****;"),
                    cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT id, username, password FROM ""YouthApp_tableuser"" where username='" & Username & "' and password='" & Password & "' ", MyCon)
                    MyCon.Open()
                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

                    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        If (Username = Username_TextBox1.Text And Password = Password_TextBox2.Text) Then
                            Username = ""
                            Password = ""

                            MainForm.Show()
                            Me.Hide()

                        End If
                    Else
                        MsgBox("Invalid User! Please Enter Correct User Name and Password.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid!")
                        Username = ""
                        Password = ""
                    End If


                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
```

Comment: Would be nice if you include the usage of sql parameters in your answer

Comment: If you declare you DataTable outside of the `Using` block you can use it after the connection is closed and disposed with `End Using` It is a bad idea to show a message box while a connection is open. What if the user went to lunch?